# oc rsh + awk prints extra indentation at beginning of each line, seems only did line break but does not return carriage

Tags: awk, openshift-client-tools

I want to filter lines of `oc rsh du -shc` output like this:

```
oc rsh broker-amq-1-2-fsbnd du -shc / 2>&1 | awk '$2=="total" {print $1}'
```

But I got no results. For local `du -shc /some/dir 2>&1` I get desired output.

```
# locally
$  du -shc ~ 2>&1
du: cannot read directory '/home/xxxx/.cache/doc': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/xxxx/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/home/xxxx/.gvfs': Permission denied
52G /home/xxxx/
52G total
```

And filtering:

```
# filtering works; search the 2nd arg "total" and print arg 1
$  du -shc ~ 2>&1 | awk '$2=="total" {print $1}' 
52G
```

And printing:

```
$ du -shc ~ 2>&1 | awk '{print $1}'
du:
du:
du:
52G
52G
```

And $2:

```
$ du -shc ~ 2>&1 | awk '{print $2}'
cannot
cannot
cannot
/home/xxx
total
```

But remotely:

```
oc rsh broker-amq-1-2-fsbnd du -shc / 2>&1 | awk '$2=="total" {print $1}'
# no output
```

And if I don't use `awk`:

```
$ oc rsh broker-amq-1-2-fsbnd du -shc / 2>&1
du: cannot read directory '/proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/proc/acpi': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/proc/scsi': Permission denied
du: cannot access '/proc/130224/task/130224/fd/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/130224/task/130224/fdinfo/3': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/130224/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/130224/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot read directory '/run/cryptsetup': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/run/secrets/rhsm': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/sys/firmware': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/yum/history/2021-12-02/1': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/yum/history/2021-12-02/2': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/yum/history/2021-12-02/4': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/yum/history/2021-12-02/3': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/machines': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/cache/ldconfig': Permission denied
1.8G    /
1.8G    total
command terminated with exit code 1
```

And, if I only print `$1`:

```
$ oc rsh broker-amq-1-2-fsbnd du -shc / 2>&1 | awk '{print $1}'
du:
   du:
      du:
         du:
            du:
               du:
                  du:
                     du:
                        du:
                           du:
                              du:
                                 du:
                                    du:
                                       du:
                                          du:
                                             du:
                                                1.8G
                                                    1.8G
                                                        command
```

Why there are extra indentations? Seems only line break is done, but no return carriage to the beginning of the line???

If I print `$2`, we can see the 2 lines at the end are aligned; what is wrong here?

```
$ oc rsh broker-amq-1-2-fsbnd du -shc / 2>&1 | awk '{print $2}'
cannot
      cannot
            cannot
                  cannot
                        cannot
                              cannot
                                    cannot
                                          cannot
                                                cannot
                                                      cannot
                                                            cannot
                                                                  cannot
                                                                        cannot
                                                                              cannot
                                                                                    cannot
                                                                                          cannot
                                                                                                /
total
terminated
```

Local `awk` version is:

```
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2016 Free Software Foundation.
```

, and remote, openshift `awk` version is

```
GNU Awk 4.0.2
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2012 Free Software Foundation.
```

and local `du` version is

```
du (GNU coreutils) 8.28
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

, while remote, openshift pod `du` version is

```
du (GNU coreutils) 8.22
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Seems remote versions are behind local versions a lot, notice the years of copyright.

As per request of @Ed Morton:

```
$ oc rsh broker-amq-1-15-snd64 du -shc / 2>/dev/null | od -c
0000000   d   u   :       c   a   n   n   o   t       r   e   a   d    
                                                                       0000020   d   i   r   e   c   t   o   r   y       '   /   p   r   o   c
                                                                                                                                              0000040   /   t   t   y   /   d   r   i   v   e   r   '   :       P   e
                       0000060   r   m   i   s   s   i   o   n       d   e   n   i   e   d  \r
                                                                                              0000100  \n   d   u   :       c   a   n   n   o   t       r   e   a   d
                                                                                                                                                                     0000120       d   i   r   e   c   t   o   r   y       '   /   p   r   o
                                              0000140   c   /   a   c   p   i   '   :       P   e   r   m   i   s   s
                                                                                                                     0000160   i   o   n       d   e   n   i   e   d  \r  \n   d   u   :    
                                                                                                                                                                                            0000200   c   a   n   n   o   t       r   e   a   d       d   i   r   e
                                                                     0000220   c   t   o   r   y       '   /   p   r   o   c   /   s   c   s
                                                                                                                                            0000240   i   '   :       P   e   r   m   i   s   s   i   o   n       d
                     0000260   e   n   i   e   d  \r  \n   d   u   :       c   a   n   n   o
                                                                                            0000300   t       a   c   c   e   s   s       '   /   p   r   o   c   /
                                                                                                                                                                   0000320   2   8   7   2   7   /   t   a   s   k   /   2   8   7   2   7
                                            0000340   /   f   d   /   3   '   :       N   o       s   u   c   h    
                                                                                                                   0000360   f   i   l   e       o   r       d   i   r   e   c   t   o   r
                                                                                                                                                                                          0000400   y  \r  \n   d   u   :       c   a   n   n   o   t       a   c
                                                                   0000420   c   e   s   s       '   /   p   r   o   c   /   2   8   7   2
                                                                                                                                          0000440   7   /   t   a   s   k   /   2   8   7   2   7   /   f   d   i
                   0000460   n   f   o   /   3   '   :       N   o       s   u   c   h    
                                                                                          0000500   f   i   l   e       o   r       d   i   r   e   c   t   o   r
                                                                                                                                                                 0000520   y  \r  \n   d   u   :       c   a   n   n   o   t       a   c
                                          0000540   c   e   s   s       '   /   p   r   o   c   /   2   8   7   2
                                                                                                                 0000560   7   /   f   d   /   4   '   :       N   o       s   u   c   h
                                                                                                                                                                                        0000600       f   i   l   e       o   r       d   i   r   e   c   t   o
                                                                 0000620   r   y  \r  \n   d   u   :       c   a   n   n   o   t       a
                                                                                                                                        0000640   c   c   e   s   s       '   /   p   r   o   c   /   2   8   7
                 0000660   2   7   /   f   d   i   n   f   o   /   4   '   :       N   o
                                                                                        0000700       s   u   c   h       f   i   l   e       o   r       d   i
                                                                                                                                                               0000720   r   e   c   t   o   r   y  \r  \n   d   u   :       c   a   n
                                        0000740   n   o   t       r   e   a   d       d   i   r   e   c   t   o
                                                                                                               0000760   r   y       '   /   r   u   n   /   c   r   y   p   t   s   e
                                                                                                                                                                                      0001000   t   u   p   '   :       P   e   r   m   i   s   s   i   o   n
                                                               0001020       d   e   n   i   e   d  \r  \n   d   u   :       c   a   n
                                                                                                                                      0001040   n   o   t       r   e   a   d       d   i   r   e   c   t   o
               0001060   r   y       '   /   r   u   n   /   s   e   c   r   e   t   s
                                                                                      0001100   /   r   h   s   m   '   :       P   e   r   m   i   s   s   i
                                                                                                                                                             0001120   o   n       d   e   n   i   e   d  \r  \n   d   u   :       c
                                      0001140   a   n   n   o   t       r   e   a   d       d   i   r   e   c
                                                                                                             0001160   t   o   r   y       '   /   s   y   s   /   f   i   r   m   w
                                                                                                                                                                                    0001200   a   r   e   '   :       P   e   r   m   i   s   s   i   o   n
                                                             0001220       d   e   n   i   e   d  \r  \n   d   u   :       c   a   n
                                                                                                                                    0001240   n   o   t       r   e   a   d       d   i   r   e   c   t   o
             0001260   r   y       '   /   v   a   r   /   l   i   b   /   y   u   m
                                                                                    0001300   /   h   i   s   t   o   r   y   /   2   0   2   1   -   0   1
                                                                                                                                                           0001320   -   2   6   /   1   '   :       P   e   r   m   i   s   s   i
                                    0001340   o   n       d   e   n   i   e   d  \r  \n   d   u   :       c
                                                                                                           0001360   a   n   n   o   t       r   e   a   d       d   i   r   e   c
                                                                                                                                                                                  0001400   t   o   r   y       '   /   v   a   r   /   l   i   b   /   y
                                                           0001420   u   m   /   h   i   s   t   o   r   y   /   2   0   2   1   -
                                                                                                                                  0001440   0   1   -   2   6   /   2   '   :       P   e   r   m   i   s
           0001460   s   i   o   n       d   e   n   i   e   d  \r  \n   d   u   :
                                                                                  0001500       c   a   n   n   o   t       r   e   a   d       d   i   r
                                                                                                                                                         0001520   e   c   t   o   r   y       '   /   v   a   r   /   l   i   b
                                  0001540   /   y   u   m   /   h   i   s   t   o   r   y   /   2   0   2
                                                                                                         0001560   1   -   0   1   -   2   6   /   4   '   :       P   e   r   m
                                                                                                                                                                                0001600   i   s   s   i   o   n       d   e   n   i   e   d  \r  \n   d
                                                         0001620   u   :       c   a   n   n   o   t       r   e   a   d       d
                                                                                                                                0001640   i   r   e   c   t   o   r   y       '   /   v   a   r   /   l
         0001660   i   b   /   y   u   m   /   h   i   s   t   o   r   y   /   2
                                                                                0001700   0   2   1   -   0   1   -   2   6   /   3   '   :       P   e
                                                                                                                                                       0001720   r   m   i   s   s   i   o   n       d   e   n   i   e   d  \r
                                0001740  \n   d   u   :       c   a   n   n   o   t       r   e   a   d
                                                                                                       0001760       d   i   r   e   c   t   o   r   y       '   /   v   a   r
                                                                                                                                                                              0002000   /   l   i   b   /   m   a   c   h   i   n   e   s   '   :    
                                                       0002020   P   e   r   m   i   s   s   i   o   n       d   e   n   i   e
                                                                                                                              0002040   d  \r  \n   d   u   :       c   a   n   n   o   t       r   e
       0002060   a   d       d   i   r   e   c   t   o   r   y       '   /   v
                                                                              0002100   a   r   /   c   a   c   h   e   /   l   d   c   o   n   f   i
                                                                                                                                                     0002120   g   '   :       P   e   r   m   i   s   s   i   o   n       d
                              0002140   e   n   i   e   d  \r  \n   3   .   7   G  \t   /  \r  \n   3
                                                                                                     0002160   .   7   G  \t   t   o   t   a   l  \r  \n
0002173
xxxxxxx@elxag5zs8d3:~
```

and:

```
$ oc rsh broker-amq-1-15-snd64 du -shc / 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}' | od -c
0000000   d   u   :  \n   d   u   :  \n   d   u   :  \n   d   u   :  \n
*
0000100   3   .   7   G  \n   3   .   7   G  \n
0000112
```

If I change `RS`, I got stranger results.

```
$ oc rsh broker-amq-1-15-snd64 du -shc / 2>/dev/null | awk 'BEGIN {RS="\r\n";} {print $1}'
du:
   du:
      du:
         du:
            du:
               du:
                  du:
                     du:
                        du:
                           du:
                              du:
                                 du:
                                    du:
                                       du:
                                          du:
                                             du:
                                                3.7G
                                                    3.7G
                                                        xxxxxx@elxag5zs8d3:~
```

Comment: Please add the output of running it locally piped to awk and getting more than 1 line of output, e.g. `du -shc ~ 2>&1 | awk '{print $1}'`. so we can see if THAT gets indented too and so narrow down the problem.

Comment: Aside: why are you doing `2>&1`? It seems like your real intent is to only match on a string like `total` in the stdout so do you REALLY want awk to parse the stderr as well as the stdout?

Comment: If I don't use `2>&1`, permission errors come out; because awk only accepts stdin and will not process stderr, but I don't want to see stderr coming out. Later I may use the output of this command in a script, so I don't want anything unrelated. Updated.

Comment: No, use `2>/dev/null` to discard stderr instead of `2>&1` to add it into the stdout if you want to ignore the errors.

Comment: Yes that works too I guess.

Comment: `2>&1` actually doesn't work as it clutters up the output and could produce false matches or other undesirable effects, e.g. maybe stderr includes some control chars that are causing what you're currently experiencing, idk, so let's eliminate that possibility by using `2>/dev/null` instead.

Comment: Thanks for adding the local tool output. Now run `oc rsh broker-amq-1-2-fsbnd du -shc / 2>/dev/null | od -c` and `oc rsh broker-amq-1-2-fsbnd du -shc / 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $1}' | od -c` and add the output of those to your question so we can see which characters are actually being output by both commands.

Comment: Both give `0000000`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243906/discussion-between-westerngun-and-ed-morton).

Comment: For future reference: seems I just switched to another environment so no output for `oc rsh`, pod name mismatch. After getting pod names again, with `od -c`, I find out that remote `du` uses line seperator `\r\n` and `awk` will translate that into `\n`. Due to unknown reason it's print like no carriage return in my terminal. I have to set `ORS="\r\n"` for `awk` to get expected output(line break + carriage return), just like local. I don't know why. Local `du` also uses `\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very odd that your `oc rsh broker-amq-1-15-snd64 du -shc / 2>/dev/null | od -c` output shows no blanks or tabs, e.g. between `cannot` and `read` in:

```
0000000 d u : c a n n o t r e a d
```

while without `od -c`, i.e. when you run `oc rsh broker-amq-1-2-fsbnd du -shc / 2>&1`, there clearly are blanks:

```
du: cannot read directory '/proc/tty/driver': Permission denied
```

Anyway, as shown in the `oc rsh broker-amq-1-15-snd64 du -shc / 2>/dev/null | od -c` output your output lines end in `\r\n`, e.g. (emphasis mine):

```
0000000 d u : c a n n o t r e a d
0000020 d i r e c t o r y ' / p r o c
0000040 / t t y / d r i v e r ' : P e
0000060 r m i s s i o n d e n i e d **\r
0000100 \n** d u : c a n n o t r e a d
0000120 d i r e c t o r y ' / p r o
0000140 c / a c p i ' : P e r m i s s
0000160 i o n d e n i e d **\r \n**
```

You mentioned that locally `du` outputs `\n`-terminated lines so that just means it's probably `rsh` or `oc` that's changing that to `\r\n` - try it with some other command like `oc rsh broker-amq-1-15-snd64 date` to verify.

In any case, to handle that simply and portably, and assuming you don't actually want `\r\n` line endings in your final output, change your awk script from this:

```
awk '$2=="total" {print $1}'
```

to this which removes the `\r` at the end of each line before doing anything else with the input:

```
awk '{sub(/\r$/,"")} $2=="total" {print $1}'
```

The reason you weren't getting output with `$2=="total"` is that given input like:

```
foo total\r\n
```

$2 isn't `"total"`, it's `"total\r"`, and so the comparison fails.

You mentioned setting `ORS="\r\n"` to get the desired output - no, that just propagates the problem to the next command.

You could set `RS="\r\n"` but that would only work in an awk that accepts multi-char RS, e.g. GNU awk, in other awks that'd be treated the same  as `RS="\r"` per the POSIX standard that says RS is a single char.

There are some platforms out there where when `\r\n` input is detected either:

1. The `\r` automatically gets stripped by the underlying C primitives that awk calls to read input, or
2. The RS automatically gets set to `\r\n`.

so just be aware of that and check what input awk is actually getting and what `RS` and `ORS` are set to if the `sub()` above doesn't do what you want (`awk 'NR==1{ print "$0=<"$0">" ORS "RS=<"RS">" ORS "ORS=<"ORS">"; exit }' | od -c` should tell you all you need to know).

For more information see [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: Yeah I agree, with `oc rsh`, `date` also outputs `\r\n`, but when I enter the pod in Openshift, that gives `\n`. So yeah, your solution is right. I got the correct result (`3.7G`). But the only thing is that the next line after the correct result is indented, like `3.7G(line break here)    xxxx@localhost:~`(notice the 4 spaces at the beginning of the second line, which matches the length of the output). So line break in my Ubuntu only needs `\n`, but why suddenly after `oc rsh` it needs `\r\n`?

Comment: And maybe there was some formatting error of StackOverflow, I edited the question to answer your question about space between `du:` and `cannot`: there are extra spaces; it's just the code format in the question with each line starting with 4 spaces is not clear, I changed to another format, now it's clear.

Comment: You;d have to ask whoever provides whatever `oc rsh` is why they chose to use DOS line endings. Please post a new followup question about the indenting with a [mcve] using your currently fixed script just about that remaining issue as there's already so much information in your question it's hard to tell what it's about any more and this may be something completely different from the DOS line endings.

Comment: Thanks for ur patience a lot! `oc` is openshift client and `oc rsh` runs command in pods. According to [a bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1668763), `--no-tty=true` will not insert CRLF at the end.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, as a side note:

`oc rsh` seems always to append CRLF after the output and there's some bug reports about that, see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1668763 and https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1638447. It says `oc rsh` requires a pseudo-terminal and with option `--no-tty=true` it will not append CRLF. Meanwhile `oc exec` will not append CRLF. It seems to come from `docker` term which both depends on.

> This would most likely have to be a patch made against the docker term[1] package, which the rsh and exec commands depend on.
>
> [1]. https://github.com/moby/moby/tree/master/pkg/term

So, the following two forms will require no stripping of `\r` afterwards, and at the same time introduce no extra indentation after execution(before xxxxxx@localhost:~):

```
oc exec broker-amq-1-15-snd64 -- du -shc / 2>/dev/null | awk '$2=="total" {print $1}'
3.6G
xxxxxx@localhost:~
```

or:

```
oc rsh --no-tty=true broker-amq-1-15-snd64 du -shc / 2>/dev/null | awk '$2=="total" {print $1}'
3.6G
xxxxxx@localhost:~
```

Note for `exec` you need `--`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a solution that neither involves forcing `oc` (or any other application) to alter it's line-ending behavior, nor having to fudge with either `FS` or `RS` ?

```
gawk -te 'NF=/\11total\15?$/'
19G
```

Tested and confirmed working on `mawk 1.3.4`, `mawk 1.9.9.6`, `macos nawk`, and `gawk 5.1.1`, including invocation flags `-c/-P/-t/-S`

I would've used `\r` instead of `\15` but `gawk -t` traditional mode was complaining about `\r` not being available, so `\15` would be the most portable solution

But if you don't need `gawk -t` compatibility and don't mind fudging `FS`, then

```
nawk NF=NF==2 FS='\ttotal\r?'
or
mawk -— —-NF FS='\ttotal\r?'
```

or even

```
mawk 'NF=!+FS<NF' FS='total$' RS='\r?\n'
```

-- `The 4Chan Teller`